# Recreating activities in Android

Tags: java, android

In an Android app, when you rotate the screen, `onCreate()` is called to paint the view and create the objects. The TextView objects recover the previous texts but the ImageView objects not. Is there a reason for that? any answer will help me to understand how Android works :)

Thank you so much,

Comment: How do you get and display the ImageView in the first place?  There must be some difference between than and what happens on a screen rotation.

Comment: If you have an ID for the view its state should be restored for you

Comment: Why texts are restored to my edited value?

Answer (score 1):

On orientation change the whole Activity is recreated. If you want to recover data after orientation change you can do that with onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState. When you change the orientation onSaveInstanceState is called to save values in a Bundle and after the Activity is recreated onRestoreInstaceState is called to load the values from the Bundle again. You can use this like this:

```
  @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // "Value" is a tag with which you can load the String again in onRestoreInstanceState.
    savedInstanceState.putString("Value", this.stringToSave);   
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // Use the tag "Value" to load the String again.
    this.stringToSave = savedInstanceState.getString("Value"); 
}
```

Comment: Hi Xaver. Your answer is nice but is not responding my question: why TextView data is maintained but not the images in the ImageView's?

Comment: Are you settings the images in the ImageView's programmatically?

Comment: Yes, but not the texts.

Comment: That's why it is not saved. Everything you set in the layouts is recovered after orientation is changed because the layouts are used to create the activities and fragments again. But what you set programatically is lost. That's why you need to save this information in onSaveInstanceState and recover it in onRestoreInstanceState.

Comment: mmmmmmmmmm okay, but if I modify the text view to "hello" for instance, after orientation change, it shows "hello"! this is where I am confused.

Comment: I think it is the default behavior of an Activity to save simple values like String in a TextView automatically. But saving a complex object like a bitmap in an ImageView has to be handled by the user. I will look this up and comment here when I have found the answer.

Comment: I have found the answer. If your Views have an id they will automatically save their state when you change orientation. If you remove the id from your Views and they should not save their text automatically on orientation change anymore.

Comment: That's not true at all. My ImageViews have ids and image is gone once I change the orientation. Wow, what a strange behavior, would be great if we found the answer!

Comment: I should have clarified a little more. TextViews and EditTexts save their state automatically, but ImageViews don't.

Comment: Ahá! Okay Xaver. Thank you so much. However, how do you know that? I mean, is there documentation about this difference between TextView/EditText and ImageView?

Comment: There is no article about this in the Android Developer Guidelines but I have tested it and I have found this article which touches upon the subject: http://tekeye.biz/2012/saving-activity-state. TextViews automatically retain their text on orientation change as long as they have an id, and because EditText is derived from TextView so do they.